# org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

When trying to start tomcat I get this error.  What could be the cause of this?

I've read through a bunch of similar posts and I can't seem to find anything that's a help.  I'm not missing a `.jar` file as far as I can tell.

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1543)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1265)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Apr 10, 2014 1:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Apr 10, 2014 1:53:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

Here are the .jar files that are included in my project:

```
annotations-api.jar     
el-api.jar          
robotium-solo-5.0.1.jar
catalina-ant.jar        
gson-2.2.4-javadoc.jar      
servlet-api.jar
catalina-ha.jar         
gson-2.2.4-sources.jar      
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
catalina-tribes.jar     
gson-2.2.4.jar          
slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar
catalina.jar            
jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar
commons-io-2.4-javadoc.jar  
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar   
tomcat-api.jar
commons-io-2.4-sources.jar  
jasper-el.jar           
tomcat-coyote.jar
commons-io-2.4-test-sources.jar 
jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar   
tomcat-dbcp.jar
commons-io-2.4-tests.jar    
jasper.jar          
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar      
json-path-0.9.0-javadoc.jar 
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.1-javadoc.jar 
json-path-0.9.0-sources.jar 
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
commons-lang3-3.3.1.jar     
json-path-0.9.0.jar     
tomcat-jdbc.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar   
json-smart-1.2.jar      
tomcat-util.jar
commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar   
jsp-api.jar         
tomcat7-websocket.jar
ecj-4.3.1.jar           
loremipsum-1.0.jar      
websocket-api.jar
```

---

**Update:**

After uninstalling and reinstalling tomcat my problem was fixed. Weird.

Comment: @drob Deleted that post, reposted because I couldn't find it after I'd posted it so I figured I had somehow not posted it.  Next time I will wait before trying to find a post I submit.

Comment: Could you add the screenshot(or listing) of the libs(and jars) included in your project? Your web.xml (try to shorten it if there are a lot of mappings) and JDK version.

Comment: Your JDK is 1.5+ and in your web.xml <web-app> version attribute is 2.5+? Because the problem seems to be related either with some library conflict or with missconfiguration. As far as I've seen your jars I cannot find that it is related to library conflict.

Comment: If so that wasn't intentional.  Where do you see that?

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling tomcat my problem was fixed.  Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot "/" in servlet-mapping. Like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

servlet-api.jar - is wrong in your list of application libs.
This jar file (or evivalent) must be supplied by servlet container (Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

I have used "invoker" in my web.xml and after too much investigation I found that its no longer after tomcat 6.

Remove this invoker and mapped all the servlet with /servlet/servlet.class.fully.qualified.name in servlet-mapping